# How to run a member function with numba.njit

Tags: python, performance, numba

I have a class called `medium` and I want to increase the perfomance of a method of this class called `train`.

```
def train(self, episodeLength, T, doPlot = False, doSave = False, savePath = "./", meanTargetRewardInvAgent = None, collectiveTargetMeanReward = None):
```

However, this method uses the keyword `self` a lot, and when I call the method like this

```
trainCompiled = numba.njit(medium.train)
trainCompiled(episodeLength, T, doPlot = True, doSave = True, savePath = s_savePath)
```

it gives

```
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: analyzing bytecode)
Variable 'self' is not defined.
```

and when I pass medium class instance as a parameter to `trainCompiled` as

```
some keyword arguments unexpected
  File "/Volumes/Junction/Workspace/CellDev/NonEqui to ML/MLtoPhysics/AnnihilationModel/mltophysics-MxNet/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    trainCompiled(medium, episodeLength, T, doPlot = True, doSave = True, savePath = s_savePath)
```

So, long story short, how can I run a member function using `numba.njit`?

Comment: `njit` (`jit` + `nopython`) seems at first glance a bit incompatible with jitting a member function. Moreover, note that [numba does not support utf-8 string](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should look [jit classes](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/jitclass.html).  "All methods of a jitclass are compiled into nopython functions".
Thus, you should decorate your class `medium` with `@jitclass`.

Comment: Apparently class members are not yet supported